# I thought that "git pull" includes merge, seems not, what am not understanding?

Tags: git

I have two branches `sw-dev` and `make`. I have the file `variables.mk` changed locally in `make` branch. In the meantime, that file changed in origin `sw-dev` repository to include line `BLK := pl/blocks`.   When I do

```
>git pull origin sw-dev
```

I expect there will be either a silent or conflict merge. No, nothing happens, everything up to date.  What am I missing??

```
>git checkout origin/sw-dev
HEAD is now at 4f391d3... Merge branch 'sw-dev' of ssh://(...)/tools/git/xdk into sw-dev
>grep BLK variables.mk
BLK := pl/blocks
>git checkout make
Switched to branch 'make'
>git pull origin sw-dev
From /tools/git/xdk
* branch            sw-dev     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
>grep BLK variables.mk
>git status variables.mk
# On branch make
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: You have not pushed to origin.

Comment: @Basilevs I don't want to push my make changes to origin. They are not ready.  I just want to integrate with the latest changes from sw-dev, which have been pushed to origin.

Comment: But the change you want is present only locally. There is no meaning in merging with remote branch then.

Comment: @Basilevs no, the change I want is present in the origin.  Look carefully at my sequence of commands.  I am showing you that my sw-dev branch is updated, and has the change. That is how I know that change is present in the origin.

Comment: Which line ensures that? You are only pulling from the orign, never push. Hence you can't be sure that remote branch has all your local changes. Use the advice in my answer to actually check origin's content.

Comment: @Basilevs if I am locally on the branch sw-dev, and I do >git pull origin sw-dev, and it says "up to date", and I have everything committed, that means, my local branch is in the same state as the origin.  And in my local branch, the change is there.  Anyway, I did your suggestion, and it shows the change is present.

Comment: @Basilevs I changed my original question, as per your suggestion

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46885/discussion-between-mark-galeck-and-basilevs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything, pull fetch the branch and merges it into your current one. Is just telling you that the branch make already contains all the commit hashes that are in origin/sw-dev. You have had to include the commit 4f391d3 into make branch at some point.

Do git log in make and look for the hash 4f391d3 to verify it.

Do git reflog to check last commands executed and see when did you do it .

Comment: thank you, yes it turns out I did not realize, that it was already merged previously with that commit, and later, accidentally, overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
git checkout origin/sw-dev
grep BLK variables.mk
```

You won't see your var due to it being absent in the origin. Use

```
git push origin sw-dev
```

to fix that.

Comment: I don't want to push my changes.  They are not ready.  I just want to integrate with the latest changes that have been pushed to origin.

Comment: >git checkout origin/sw-dev
HEAD is now at 4f391d3... Merge branch 'sw-dev' of ssh://(...)/tools/git/xdk into sw-dev
> grep BLK variables.mk
BLK := pl/blocks